# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty x^{\lambda-1} \exp\left(-ax-b\sqrt x-\frac{c}{\sqrt x} - \frac{d}{x}\right) \: dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

Is there a closed form for the integral 
$$\int_0^\infty x^{\lambda-1} \exp\left(-ax-b\sqrt x-\frac{c}{\sqrt x} - \frac{d}{x}\right) \: dx?$$

where $\lambda>0$, $a>0$, $d>0$ and where $b$, $c$ could be any real number. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried any substitutions? I'd write it "positively" as integral over $\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{x}(a^2x+bx^{3/2}+cx^{1/2}+d)\right)}$ and then start thinking. My goal would be to press it in the form of a sum of [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition)s. I expect the real question is the process of how to break the thing apart to isolate the end that'll look like $\lim_{y\to 0}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{y}}=0$.

Comment: I haven't tried any particular substitutions. I don't think it's obvious what we should directly substitute into this integral. Instead I was considering using integral transformation methods.

Answer (score 2):

Due to [Glasser's master theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html), in some non-trivial cases the integral can be represented in terms of Bessel $K$ functions, but I won't bet a penny on the existence of a nice closed form for any value of $(a,b,c,d,\lambda)$ in some open set.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int_0^\infty x^{\lambda-1}e^{-ax-b\sqrt x-\frac{c}{\sqrt x}-\frac{d}{x}}~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty(\sqrt x)^{\lambda-1}e^{-ax^2-bx-\frac{c}{x}-\frac{d}{x^2}}~d(\sqrt x)$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{\lambda}{2}-1}e^{-ax^2-bx-\frac{c}{x}-\frac{d}{x^2}}~dx$